# Getting SVG pie chart to only animate once

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, pie-chart

I got this simple SVG pie chart loader (http://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/):

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/gFnw9/6/

**How do I get it to only animate once?** Bonus points for helping me remove unnecessary code.

HTML:

```
<svg width="250" height="250" viewbox="0 0 250 250">
  <path id="loader" transform="translate(125, 125) scale(.84)" />
</svg>
```

JS:

```
var $loader = $('#loader'),
    alpha = 0,
    pi = Math.PI,
    time = 5;

function draw() {
  alpha++;
  alpha %= 360;

  var r = ( alpha * pi / 180 ),
    x = Math.sin( r ) * 125,
    y = Math.cos( r ) * - 125,
    mid = ( alpha > 180 ) ? 1 : 0,
    animate = 'M 0 0 v -125 A 125 125 1 ' 
           + mid + ' 1 ' 
           +  x  + ' ' 
           +  y  + ' z';

  loader.setAttribute( 'd', animate );

  setTimeout(draw, time); // Redraw
};

draw.call(this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get it to animate only once you need to stop calling the setTimeout() once alpha is > 360. Then you need to make sure that the svg circle is fully drawn.

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gFnw9/12/

```
var $loader = $('#loader'),
    alpha = 0,
    pi = Math.PI,
    time = 5;

function draw() {
  alpha++;

  var r = ( alpha * pi / 180 ),
    x = Math.sin( r ) * 125,
    y = Math.cos( r ) * - 125,
    mid = ( alpha >= 180 ) ? 1 : 0,
    animate = 'M 0 0 v -125 A 125 125 1 ' 
           + mid + ' 1 ' 
           +  x  + ' ' 
           +  y  + ' z';

    if (alpha < 360){
      setTimeout(draw, time); // Redraw
    }else{
        animate = "M 0 0 v -125 A 125 125 1 1 1 -.1 -125 z";
    }

  loader.setAttribute( 'd', animate );

};

draw.call(this);
```

Comment: Thanks! Came up with this meanwhile though: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/gFnw9/13/ -- what do you think?

Comment: thats cool you just need to make sure the pie chart doesn't disappear at the end... so draw it one more time as a full circle

Comment: I was looking for the similar thing, but I needed it in the countdown style - the pie had to vanish once it ran out of time. Here's the modified fiddle in case someone is searching:  [jsfiddle.net/gFnw9/82/](http://jsfiddle.net/gFnw9/82/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you definetly don't have to do this with SVG. Check out this great tutorial. it might help.

[Tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/)

Comment: This one has to be SVG. I actually got the code from the tutorial you linked to.